# DOCTYPE XHTML 1.0 issue + Scroll bar is not appearing in IE6

Tags: xhtml

Hii,
 I'm using the DOCTYPE is DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
I have set the overflow property of the div is not working in IE 6 but it is taking in IEs higher versions

i.e. I have set like this

```
<div style='overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; height: 370px'></div>
```

Comment: Is the doctype relevant? Ie. when you try with a different doctype, does the problem disappear?

Comment: When i try with HTML 4.0 it is working

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search indicates that the overflow property is buggy in IE6.  Have you tried either "auto" for either overflow-x and overflow-y?

Unless you're working on a business app that's only compatible with IE6. why are you supporting this version of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

If it works with HTML doctype I’d suggest using plain HTML instead of XHTML. XHTML on the web is mostly broken and unless you really need it (which I doubt), you’d save yourself trouble. For example the HTML5 doctype works as expected in all browsers and you can actually *remember it:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```